# Embedding Firefox in a nodejs Dockerfile for Linux

Tags: node.js, docker, firefox

Does anyone know how to embed firefox in a dockerfile for linux. I got this code for embedding chrome in a docker container but I don't know how to change it to embed firefox in the dockerfile.
This is my [dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzuqI.png)

I tried using npm install firefox but had no luck.

Comment: I think you need to add => RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y firefox-esr

Comment: Quick question: why? What is this firefox going to be doing? Because depending on that answer there might be very different things you may want to do instead.

Comment: follow this link might be helpful https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/node-firefox/dockerfile

Comment: It's 2023, so rather than selenium with webdriver, you almost certainly want to use `playwright` instead, which doesn't need webdriver, and lets you use chrome, firefox, _and_ webkit.

Comment: I'm using puppeteer and puppeteer is not able to handle personal certification. Therefore, I'm using firefox as firefox is the only browser that can handle certificates, we can reuse saved certificates without any browser level notification or alert. Chrome gives alerts for each and every certificate but puppeteer is unable to handle those kind of requests.